# Do I need a Hong Kong transit visa to travel to China from India

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, hong-kong

I wish to travel to China and best budgeted way is to travel via Hong Kong. So do I need a Hong Kong transit visa for that?

Also, If I travel by train, does that require a transit visa ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a Hong Kong transit visa if I travel to India from USA via Hong Kong airport (Cathay Pacific)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53540/do-i-need-a-hong-kong-transit-visa-if-i-travel-to-india-from-usa-via-hong-kong-a)

Comment: HK used to have the policy which allow any people enter to HK for not more than 7 days when they travel to a third country. However i don't know such policy is cancelled or changed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are an Indian passport holder, then you do not need a visa to enter Hong Kong and you are allowed to stay there for a maximum of 14 days. Please refer to the link below:

http://www.discoverhongkong.com/in/plan-your-trip/traveller-info/immigration-and-customs/visa-information.jsp

The second part of your question - I am not sure i understand it. Do you wish to travel to Hong Kong from India through train? If that is the case, I am not sure how it works. Either you pass through China or Myanmar ([check visa requirements for Indians in Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Myanmar))

Since I do not know from which part of India you are travelling from I would recommend you take a look at this page on a travel forum for more information

https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-indian-subcontinent/topics/train-from-delhi-to-hongkong